# OpenGL uniform block works in vertex shader only if defined in fragment shader. Separable shader programs

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I have a UBO defined in my vertex shader as follows:

```
layout (std140) uniform matricesBuffer
{
    mat4 MVPMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
};
```

I spent ages figuring out why the matrix I needed wasn't getting through. Then I added the same uniform block to the fragment shader, and it magically worked. So my question is, I know there are specifications about interface matching between shader programs/stages when using separable shaders in a pipeline, but from what I've read these only describe the in and out variables, but this uniform block, or UBO it is, should be accessible from just the vertex shader, as I linked the UBO to that binding point. I'm confused about this, any info would be appreciated.

Edit: I've been trying some things, putting just:

```
layout (std140) uniform anyName
{
    mat4 worldMatrix;
};
```

in the fragment shader makes it work. And if I change "anyName" to certain names it either works or doesn't. For example if it starts with the letter R it doesn't work, then most other letters it works. So confused.

Comment: There is no requirement for separate programs to use the same uniforms (of any kind). So more than likely, the problem is in your code somewhere.

Comment: @Thank you. I'm so tired, my eyes are hurting, gonna go to sleep and tackle this later.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas My understanding of the bindings of the shader blocks to the UBOs was completely wrong. This picture helped me: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Capture2.jpg

If I call glGetUniformBlockIndex() on one shader and bind the UBO to it, and then bind the UBO to another shader block index, the first block loses the binding right? As the UBO can only be bound to one index? Is there a way to make the binding index explicit in each shader? Say set it to 1 in all shaders.

Comment: Those are very different questions from the one you've asked here. So you may want to ask them formally.